# prevent of sleeping not work

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

i need to prevent mt app from sleeping.

so , at first i add this permission :

```
      < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

the below codes in Activity :

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     PowerManager.WakeLock wl= pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"sleeplock");
```

too , in app installing show permission:

[image]

But after all above Efforts, `the Device fall to asleep(Off)` yet!

**where is problem?**

Comment: are you referring `sleep` as `screen-off`?

Comment: @waqaslam , yes - screen fall off yet,

Comment: Then Better include `android:keepScreenOn="true"` to any of your view in xml layout. This will keep the screen on as long as the view is in foreground. With this technique, you dont even need to implement wakelocks.

Comment: @waqaslam , you mean i should use android:keepScreenOn="true" in all if layouts?

Comment: just add that to any one of the view in your activity.

Comment: @waqaslam , tanx - it work - just is not any way that i just define once and it work in all of app?

Comment: Well, it depends on your design. If all the Activities in your project are extending from a custom activity-class (which I personally recommend) then you may also put this programmatically in onCreate - so that you dont need to write it each time.

Comment: @waqaslam OK - i have one activity and other are fragment , now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58608/discussion-between-saeid-and-waqaslam).

Comment: Good! then simply set this to one of your view at activity level, and it should work fine regardless of the number of fragments you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to `acquire()` the `WakeLock` to have it take effect.

Second, if your application has a UI, and you only want to keep the screen on while your UI is in the foreground, remove all of your `WakeLock` logic and just call `setKeepScreenOn(true)` on any widget in your UI.

Comment: i try acquire() and release()- but not work yet, i use android:keepScreenOn="true" and it work; - is not any way that i just define once and it work in all of app?

Comment: @saeid: "i try acquire() and release()- but not work yet" -- you are using a partial `WakeLock`, which only keeps the CPU on, with no effect on the screen. "is not any way that i just define once and it work in all of app?" -- I would very strongly suggest that you stick with `android:keepScreenOn="true"`. You then no longer need the `WAKE_LOCK` permission, and you do not run into the problem of how to properly handle when your app moves to the background (and screen behavior should return to normal).

Answer (score 2):

Read The Friendly Manual: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

You need to call:

```
wl.acquire()
```

And then

```
wl.release()
```

Comment: i try - but not work yet, i use android:keepScreenOn="true" and it work;